# In python, how can I add a patch decorator that does not add a mock input argument?

Tags: python, timezone, patch

In python, how can I add a patch that does not add a mock input argument?

I want to add a patch on all methods in a class like so:

```
@patch('django.utils.timezone.now', return_value=datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 22, tzinfo=timezone.utc))
class TestmanyMethods(unittest.TestCase):
    # my test methods here
```

But when I do that, a mock must be added to all test methods.
How can I patch the function without adding the mock input to all test methods?

Answer (score 4):

One can do this by using the new keyword arg in the patch like so:

```
@patch('django.utils.timezone.now', new=Mock(return_value=datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 22, tzinfo=timezone.utc)))
class TestmanyMethods(unittest.TestCase):
    # my test methods here
```

With that, the mock input is not added to the class's test methods

Comment: Worth noting that the reason the decorator added a parameter to the method is to give you access to the mock object. If you supply the `new` keyword, presumably you have an opportunity to get your own reference to the object if needed.

Comment: I agree that's why the mock exists as an input parameter. If you want to completely hard code a value without editing the input signatures of the methods then this solution is needed.